# Tonemap Fuse for Fusion based on Timothy Lottes algorithm (Lua)

Tags: lua

I'm trying to build a Fuse (Fusion studio plugin) based on the tone mapper by Timothy Lottes : http://32ipi028l5q82yhj72224m8j.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/GdcVdrLottes.pdf

presented in this algorithm: https://github.com/Opioid/tonemapper/blob/master/tonemapper.py#L14-L42

The Fuse is accepted by Fusion, but crashes when I'm trying to use it. Could anyone give me some feedback please at what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

(Fuses are written in Lua)

```
    --[[

Tone Mapper based on

http://32ipi028l5q82yhj72224m8j.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/GdcVdrLottes.pdf

https://github.com/Opioid/tonemapper/blob/master/tonemapper.py#L14-L42

version 2021 01 05 by Pieter Dumoulin

]]--

FuRegisterClass("ToneMapper", CT_SourceTool, {
    REGS_Category = "Fuses",
    REGS_Name = "Tone Mapper",
    REGS_OpIconString = "TM",
    REGS_OpDescription = "Tone Mapper",
    REG_OpNoMask = true
    })

function Create()

    InContrast = self:AddInput("Contrast", "Contrast", {
        LINKID_DataType = "Number",
        INPID_InputControl = "SliderControl",
        INP_MinAllowed = 0,
        INP_MaxScale = 5,
        INP_Default = 1.2,
        })
        
    InShoulder = self:AddInput("Shoulder", "Shoulder", {
        LINKID_DataType = "Number",
        INPID_InputControl = "SliderControl",
        INP_MinAllowed = 0,
        INP_MaxScale = 5,
        INP_Default = 0.97,
        })
        
     InMidIn = self:AddInput("Middle Grey In", "mid_in", {
        LINKID_DataType = "Number",
        INPID_InputControl = "SliderControl",
        INP_MinAllowed = 0,
        INP_MaxScale = 1,
        INP_Default = 0.4,
        })
        
     InMidOut = self:AddInput("Middle Grey Out", "mid_out", {
        LINKID_DataType = "Number",
        INPID_InputControl = "SliderControl",
        INP_MinAllowed = 0,
        INP_MaxScale = 1,
        INP_Default = 0.18,
        })
        
     InHdrMax = self:AddInput("HdrMax", "Hdr_Max", {
        LINKID_DataType = "Number",
        INPID_InputControl = "SliderControl",
        INP_MinAllowed = 0,
        INP_MaxScale = 100,
        INP_Default = 64,
        })
            
    InImage = self:AddInput("Input", "Input", {
        LINKID_DataType = "Image",
        LINK_Main = 1,
        })
 
    OutImage = self:AddOutput("Output", "Output", {
        LINKID_DataType = "Image",
        LINK_Main = 1,
        })               
end


function maxrgbfunc()
    if p.R == p.G == p.B then return p.G 
            
    elseif p.G == math.max(p.R, p.B) then return p.G 
            
    elseif p.B == math.max(p.G, p.R) then return p.B 
            
    elseif p.R == math.max(p.G, p.B) then return p.R 
                
    else return math.max(p.R, math.max(p.G, p.B))
    
end

function tonemapfunc()
    local peak = math.min(maxRGB, self_hdr_max)
    local curve = (peak ^ self_a) / (((peak ^ self_a) ^ self_d) * self_b + self_c)
    return curve

end
        
function Process(req)
    local img = InImage:GetValue(req)
    
    local a = InContrast:GetValue(req).Value
    local d = InShoulder:GetValue(req).Value
    local mid_in = InMidIn:GetValue(req).Value
    local mid_out = InMidOut:GetValue(req).Value
    local hdr_max = InHdrMax:GetValue(req).Value
        
    local ad = a * d
    local midi_pow_a  = mid_in ^ a
    local midi_pow_ad = mid_in ^ ad
    local hdrm_pow_a  = hdr_max ^ a
    local hdrm_pow_ad = hdr_max ^ ad
    local u = hdrm_pow_ad * mid_out - midi_pow_ad * mid_out
    local v = midi_pow_ad * mid_out
        
    local self_a = a
    local self_d = d
    local self_b = -((-midi_pow_a + (mid_out * (hdrm_pow_ad * midi_pow_a - hdrm_pow_a * v)) / u) / v)
    local self_c = (hdrm_pow_ad * midi_pow_a - hdrm_pow_a * v) / u
    local self_hdr_max = hdr_max
            
    local out = Image({IMG_Like = img})

    self:DoMultiProcess(nil, { In = img, Out = out, MaxRGB = maxrgb }, img.Height, function (y)
            local p = Pixel()
            for x=0,In.Width-1 do
                In:GetPixel(x,y, p)
        
                maxRGB = maxrgbfunc(x, y, p)

                local peak = tonemapfunc(maxRGB, self_hdr_max, self_a, self_d, self_b, self_c, x, y, p)
        
                local ratioR = p.R / maxRGB
                local ratioG = p.G / maxRGB
                local ratioB = p.B / maxRGB             
        
                p.R = peak * ratioR
                p.G = peak * ratioG
                p.B = peak * ratioB         
        
                Out:SetPixel(x,y, p)
        end
        end)
    end
        
    OutImage:Set(req,out)

end
```

Comment: Seems you're using `self` in some places but did not define it in the function args, is this some global `self`? can you be sure that `self` exists and has the functions you are trying to call? can you provide any error text?

Comment: @Nifim self:AddInput appears in various "fuse" examples. I gues it's some global in this context. https://www.steakunderwater.com/VFXPedia/96.0.243.189/index8be6.html?title=Eyeon:Script/Reference/Applications/Fuse/Example_Fuses

Comment: `if p.R == p.G == p.B then` is doing not what you want.

Comment: `maxrgbfunc()` has wrongly balanced `if`-`end`.